# Cypress.io make async request in custom login command

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, async-await, cypress

I want to configure a custom `login` command in which I have to make a signIn call which returns a promise.

`commands.js`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  AuthLib.signIn(username, password).then((data) => {
    cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", data.accessToken);
  });
```

`AuthLib.signIn()` returns a promise.

Then I want to use this command in an `before` block:

```
  before(() => {
    cy.login();
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
```

I notice that the promise is not resolved.
A 'hacky' fix would be to add `cy.wait(4000)` between `login()` and `saveLocalStorage()`.
But that makes my test depend on the loading time of the auth server

I found this 'related' issue: [Cypress.io How to handle async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980311/cypress-io-how-to-handle-async-code) where https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise is referred. But this library cannot be used in `before` or `beforeEach`

How can I await the promise returned from `login()` / make sure the promise from `login()` is resolved before doing `cy.saveLocalStorage()`?

**Update**

I added the examples of what works and does not work in : [https://github.com/Nxtra/Cypress-Amplify-Auth-Example/blob/main/cypress/support/commands.js](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64392412)

A solution would be to start with `cy.then()`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  cy.then(() => AuthLib.signIn(username, password)).then((data) => {
    cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", data.accessToken);
  });
```

Comment: This is simply legendary. I struggle with it for hours and can verify that cy.then(...) approach is the ONLY one which works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you return that promise inside `Cypress.Commands.add` callback.
It's a bit confusing to deal with promises in Cypress context, since a lot of async behavior is magically handled within cy. commands.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  return AuthLib.signIn(username, password).then((data) => {
    cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", data.accessToken);
  });
});
```

---

Other solution:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  return AuthLib.signIn(username, password);
});

before(() => {
  cy.login();
  cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", data.accessToken);
});
```

Comment: In the `before` block, should I then await the login:  `await login()`?

Comment: Either calling making `before` async and calling `await cy.login()` or just calling `cy.login()` makes that the test keeps hanging in the `before` function.

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting `cy.login()` should work. Adding other solution to original answer.

Comment: I have the feeling one cannot return a Promise from a Cypress command. Unless it is wrapped in `cy.then()`. That's the only way I got it working (see update in question). I have tried your suggestions but then Cypress keeps on hanging on the promise.