# How can I wait for a request to load in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, api, automated-tests, httprequest, cypress

I'm writing automate test on Cypress and I want to wait for a page to load.
There is a request named "Availability" that if it passes with statusCode:200 then the page loads.

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
cy.intercept('POST' , '*/api/Availability/*').as('availability') 

cy.wait('@availability').its('response.statusCode').should('eq' , 200)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: reffer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980311/cypress-io-how-to-handle-async-code

Comment: Your code looks correct. Is there any errors your facing or can you explain what is the desired behavior you're trying to achieve and what is preventing that ?

Comment: I want the test to wait until the data loads but it didn't happen. the test continued & the it failed because the selected elements weren't found on the page.

Comment: & I set a timeout for 20000ms, till this 20000ms, the request gets passed in it got 200 status code but still, I get the following message from cypress:  cy.wait() timed out waiting 20000ms for the 1st request to the route: availability. No request ever occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is your page visit?

If it's here, it won't work

```js
cy.visit(...)
cy.intercept('POST' , '*/api/Availability/*').as('availability') 
cy.wait('@availability').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

You need to set up the intercept before the app sends the api request.

```js
cy.intercept('POST' , '*/api/Availability/*').as('availability') 
cy.visit(...)
cy.wait('@availability').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)
```

Comment: My page visit is in my JSON file.... now I should visit the new URL again?Also thanks for the answer

Comment: Also, I'm adding this wait on the second page of my application, but by entering ith's URL, I get direct to the main page....what should I do now?

Comment: ***My page visit is in my JSON file*** - please be more specific, is this the `baseUrl` setting Cypress.json?

Comment: if I use page visit, I will redirect to the landing page and that fails my test.

Comment: Not helpful. What do you do to load the page? You must be doing something to get the app in the browser.

Comment: I visit the app in cypress.json file and when I write the cy.visit again, I redirect to the first page which is the landing page and tha't fails my test