# Cypress doesn't take screenshots in CLI mode

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm trying to take a simple screenshot using Cypress, however, it only works in the Cypress GUI (`cypress open`).
Whenever I run `cypress run`, it shows that the test succeeded but there's not screenshot saved.

This my code:

```
describe('Snapshot', () => 
    it.only('Take snapshot', async () => {
       cy.visit("http://www.google.com");
       cy.screenshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you log the screenshot command to see if it gets executed.

Comment: @PhilipAllStar I tried to but it didn't seem to log anything, it just outputs `Tests Passed` and in the `Screenshots` line, it says `Screenshots: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, even in the GUI you may get inconsistent behaviour with the code you've provided: you should try to refactor your tests to avoid the use of `async`.

Cypress already does a lot of async stuff itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49980928/1657610) for more information about how cypress uses promises, and avoiding `async`, as well as a few things you could try if you really want to use `async`.

Your code will successfully create screenshots under `cypress run` if you remove the `async` keyword like this:

```
describe('Snapshot', () => {
    it.only('Take snapshot', () => {
       cy.visit("http://www.google.com");
       cy.screenshot();
    });
});
```

*Note: I also added the missing opening brace `{` at the end of the first line. Since you say this code ran for you in the GUI, I'm assuming the brace was not the issue but was simply lost while posting.*