# How do I break for loop in cypress when a specific value shows up on screen?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, automation, cypress

Here it's going to the new page by clicking the next button again and again. One of the page has text 'abc' that I'm trying to find.

```
for(let n = 0; n < 150; n ++) {

    cy.get('.Next-Button').click();
    // some test code..

    cy.get('.selector').then($body => {
        if ($body.find('abc').length > 0) {
            return false; //used this to break the loop
        }
    });
}
```

The logic behind below code might not be clear but I basically want it to get out of loop when some value say 'abc' shows up on screen and continue with the code outside the for loop. But here it just keeps running the loop even after the value is found.

Comment: To break out of a loop, use `break;`. You're `return`ing within your `then` callback.

Comment: @mykaf I tried using `break;` but got this: **Jump target cannot cross function boundary**. Looked it up and it was suggested to use `return`

Answer (score 4):

The basic answer is **no you cannot use a for-loop and break out**.

That's because the loop is putting 150 commands into the test queue ***before*** any evaluation of the DOM like `$body.find('abc')` takes place.

The correct way to "loop" in Cypress is shown here [Cypress test for element existence conditionally with retry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73087852/16997707).

But you need an additional step which is `cy.get('.Next-Button').click()`.

Here are the changes I would make

```js
function elementExists(selector, callback, attempt = 0) {

  const interval = 100;  // 100ms between tries
  if (attempt * interval > Cypress.config('defaultCommandTimeout')) {
    cy.log(selector, 'not found')
    return cy.wrap(false, {log:false})      
  }

  return cy.get('body', {log:false}).then(($body) => {
    const element = $body.find(selector)
    if (element.length) {
      cy.log(selector, 'found')
      return cy.wrap(true, {log:false}) 
    } else {
      callback()
      cy.wait(interval, {log:false})  
      return elementExists(selector, ++attempt)
    }
  })
}

elementExists(selector, () => {
  cy.get('.Next-Button').click();
  // some test code..
})
.should(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to use a for-loop is to have a `found` variable to control the execution inside the loop.

Here is a runnable test using `example.com` and testing for the `<h1>` which is present from the start, so the loop should break on first iteration

```js
it('breaks the loop', () => {

  cy.visit('http://example.com')

  let found = false

  for (let n = 0; n < 150; n ++) {

    cy.then(() => {

      if (!found) {
        cy.log(index)
        cy.get('body').then($body => {
          if ($body.find('h1').length > 0) {
            cy.log('found')
            found = true
          }
        })
      } else {
        // cy.get('.Next-Button').click();     // do this on else branch
        // some test code..
      }
    })
  })
})
```

[image]

---

**Using cy.then() wrapper**

This is crucial, since Cypress code runs on a queue system.

If I comment out the `cy.then()` it fails to break the loop

```js
it('breaks the loop', () => {
  cy.visit('http://example.com')

  let found = false

  for (let n = 0; n < 150; n ++) {

    // cy.then(() => {

      if (!found) {
        cy.log(index)
        cy.get('body').then($body => {
          if ($body.find('h1').length > 0) {
            cy.log('found')
            found = true
          }
        })
      } else {
        // cy.get('.Next-Button').click();     // do this on else branch
        // some test code..
      }
    // })
  })
})
```

Result:

[image]